# Microsoft RAP (Risk Assessment Program)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Do you think Microsoft's RAP program worth the money you pay ?
Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe provide a link to the RAP program?  How much money would it cost you? What risks would they access?  What industry do you work in? How does your company balance risk and efficiency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would have to say that it depends on a number of factors.  First how knowledgeable are you at configuring and maintaining the specific versions of SQL Server that they would be looking at?  Then why are you doing the SQL RAP?  Is it to really get a good risk assessment, to demonstrate to management that things are being done correctly, or to learn where you are coming up short in an effort to correct things and find areas to learn more about the product, or is it none of the above?

I had a SQL RAP done at the end of last year, and I can tell you from personal experience, you will only get as much from it as you are open to learning.  If you have a cluster, be prepared to have your eyes opened to areas you never thought to look at.  The SQL RAP visit has four different phases, or at least mine did.  First they collect the data from your SQL Servers using pssdiag and a bunch of other neat tools that they leave copies of most with you.  Then they go into analysis, where they take the data and perform a very thorough analysis of it and generate reports and recommendations.  Then they sit down with you and management if you so chose and go over everything, what was good, what was iffy, and what was bad.  Then the last part they sit down with you as a DBA and teach you how to use the tools they used and that they can leave copies of with you.  They go over the PAL Tool, SQL Nexus, and some others and make sure that you know how to use these tools to do self analysis.  Best of all, they leave you these really detailed reports that you can use as a self check for setting up new environments in the future.

Is it worth it?  You probably can't tell that until you are done with it.  For me, I'd recommend it to anyone who wants to know more about running a "Best Practice" implementation of SQL Server, and who'd like some one on one learning time with a Senior Microsoft Field Engineer.

Answer (score 2):

Oh boy, is that all they does with this much hyped RAP.

Pssdiag is already done.
We did the PAL and Nexus and they too did it before.
They took around 20 Gigs of size trace files to analyse.

Now, wanted to do RAP. Holy cRAP, if this is the same thing to do again, what that's for.

I expect much more than this level of analysis without which I think this is useless and waste of money.

Answer (score 2):

I've been a part of 2 RAPs for SharePoint (finished my second 2 weeks ago). I am unsure as to how much it costs (the company I work for gets 3 RAPs a year with MS) but it is most definitely worth it.

Starting 2010, the PFE will leave the RAP tool installed on the data collection machine. This means that for up to a year, you can rerun the full RAP as many times as you want and analyze the results.

The RAP tool (for SharePoint) runs a bunch of tests that are categorized as below:

- SQL Configuration (24)
- Server Health (4)
- Server Configuration (7)
- MOSS Configuration (2)

Each test produces a list of issues with detailed recommendations on how to resolve them.

Additionally, a competent PFE (and they are) will help troubleshoot any outstanding issues you have in your environment and give you the opportunity to *listen and learn*.

I would recommend the MS RAP to all SharePoint (and SQL) Admins.

Answer (score 1):

If you have never had one, then I think you will have benefit from going through it at least one time.  I warn you that it can be quite humbling.

Comment: It can be very useful the first time. Once you know what they are looking for and how they get it you can do it yourself from then on.